# How do you get Redis connections working within an Amazon VPC private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, redis

I have an Amazon VPC setup with a private subnet containing 2 instances. One of them has redis running on it, the other instance I want to use to connect to the redis server. I have the redis instance listening on port 6123. When I connect locally on the Redis instance, everything works, but when I try to connect from the other instance on the subnet I get:

```
Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis
```

I setup two separate VPC security groups, one for the redis server, allowing inbound connections on port 6123 using the other instance's security group as the source. Likewise, I added a rule to the security group for the other instance to allow outbound traffic on port 6123 to the redis-instance (using the redis instance's security group as the destination).

Is there something I'm forgetting here? Another rule that I have to add? Or a special route I have to setup?

Thanks for any help/direction,
Tom

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default redis listens on 127.0.0.1 have you edited your redis.conf to include the line `bind your.private.ip.address` ?

Comment: yea that was it! thanks a lot for the info 8) It's strange though because I added an ICMP rule using the same method to try and ping the redis server but none of the packets went through. oh well this will work. Thanks again!

Comment: To make your Redis server accessible from external IP addresses, just comment out the bind line.

Comment: @BenGotow Thanks for the solution. Was struggling with this for a while.